# 2 SBS 2008 on same domain to transfer data for limited time

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I will be transferring data from an older SBS 2008 to a newer SBS 2008 server. I plan to set as much as possible up offsite on the newer server first, and then take onsite to complete. However, this will put 2 SBS 2008 servers on the same domain.

So, if I rename the domain of the original SBS 2008, and have the correct domain on the newer SBS 2008 will this effect any of the systems joined to the domain? Will I have to manually go to each system, and rejoin it since it will be a new server?

End result is I need to new SBS 2008 server setup with all the data, and all the workstations still joined with as little downtime as possible without violating MS TOS. Is there a tool that can do this quickly since 2 SBS can't be on same domain? Has anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you provide.

Comment: Rather than writing a lengthy treatise on what you need to do to accomplish your desired objective, I'll just suggest that you do yourself a favor and purchase the appropriate migration kit here and follow it - http://www.sbsmigration.com/

Answer (score 1):

Domains are not identified by a name - renaming the domain will keep all the systems still in the old domain. The users in the new domain will be separate users (separate profile folder). Generally: THis concept does not work.